# pip3 can't install jq on macOS due to ruby dependencies

Tags: python, ruby, pip, jq

I am trying to install a specific `jq` version in my virtual pyenv environment with the command below:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt has this line among others: `jq==1.0.2`

The error message:

```
Downloaded https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-1.6.tar.gz
    Executing: autoreconf -i
    glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
    glibtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
    glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
    glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
    glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
    glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
    glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
    glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
    configure.ac:7: warning: The macro `AC_CONFIG_HEADER' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:7: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/status.m4:719: AC_CONFIG_HEADER is expanded from...
    configure.ac:7: the top level
    configure.ac:36: warning: The macro `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:36: You should run autoupdate.
    m4/libtool.m4:100: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
    configure.ac:36: the top level
    configure.ac:46: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:46: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
    configure.ac:46: the top level
    configure.ac:54: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_TIME' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:54: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:743: AC_HEADER_TIME is expanded from...
    configure.ac:54: the top level
    configure.ac:60: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:60: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
    configure.ac:60: the top level
    configure.ac:68: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:68: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
    configure.ac:68: the top level
    configure.ac:87: warning: AC_OUTPUT should be used without arguments.
    configure.ac:87: You should run autoupdate.
    configure.ac:17: warning: The macro `AC_PROG_CC_STDC' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:17: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/c.m4:1666: AC_PROG_CC_STDC is expanded from...
    configure.ac:17: the top level
    configure.ac:59: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:59: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:59: the top level
    configure.ac:64: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:64: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:64: the top level
    configure.ac:68: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:68: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:68: the top level
    configure.ac:72: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:72: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:72: the top level
    configure.ac:76: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:76: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:76: the top level
    configure.ac:80: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:80: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:80: the top level
    configure.ac:84: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:84: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    configure.ac:84: the top level
    configure.ac:135: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
    configure.ac:135: You should run autoupdate.
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:1534: AC_ARG_ENABLE is expanded from...
    configure.ac:135: the top level
    Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --disable-maintainer-mode --with-oniguruma=/private/var/folders/fb/bh6d9vgn3lndrfb8k3gxmb5r0000gn/T/pip-install-77pax3w4/jq/_deps/onig-install-6.9.4
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./config/install-sh -c -d
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for mawk... no
    checking for nawk... no
    checking for awk... awk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
    checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
    checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
    checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
    checking for ar... ar
    checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
    checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
    checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
    checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... (cached) yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
    checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... (cached) none needed
    checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
    checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for bison... bison -y
    checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
    checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
    checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for archiver @FILE support... no
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
    checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
    checking for mt... no
    checking if : is a manifest tool... no
    checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
    checking for nmedit... nmedit
    checking for lipo... lipo
    checking for otool... otool
    checking for otool64... no
    checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
    checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
    checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
    checking for stdio.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin20.3.0 dyld
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... yes
    checking for valgrind... no
    configure: WARNING: valgrind is required to test jq.
    checking for memmem... yes
    checking for mkstemp... yes
    checking for shlwapi.h... no
    checking for bundle... bundle
    checking for Ruby dependencies... configure: WARNING: The following gems are missing
     * rake (10.4.2)
     * i18n (0.7.0)
     * json (1.8.3)
     * minitest (5.8.0)
     * thread_safe (0.3.5)
     * tzinfo (1.2.2)
     * activesupport (4.2.3)
     * addressable (2.3.8)
     * builder (3.2.2)
     * launchy (2.4.3)
     * liquid (3.0.6)
     * maruku (0.7.2)
     * rack (1.6.4)
     * sass (3.4.16)
     * rack-protection (1.5.3)
     * tilt (2.0.1)
     * sinatra (1.4.6)
     * watch (0.1.0)
     * yui-compressor (0.12.0)
     * bonsai (1.4.9)
     * hpricot (0.8.6)
     * mustache (0.99.8)
     * rdiscount (2.1.8)
     * ronn (0.7.3)
    Install missing gems with `bundle install`
    *****************************************************************
    *  Ruby dependencies for building jq documentation not found.   *
    *  You can still build, install and hack on jq, but the manpage *
    *  will not be rebuilt and some of the tests will not run.      *
    *  See docs/README.md for how to install the docs dependencies. *
    *****************************************************************
    no
```

It looks like this error is due to missing Ruby dependencies. I read on [jq documentation](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#macos) that

> (2) If you get error messages involving pipenv and if you do not need
> the documentation to be "built", then add the --disable-docs flag to
> ./configure, e.g.
>
> ./configure --disable-docs

But I don't know how to use this configure parameter when I am installing jq via pip3.

The [documentation](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#macos) also shows how to install dependencies for docs:

```
Install Dependencies (RVM, for docs)

Note that as of February 26, 2019, ruby is no longer a dependency for building jq from "master"; python is used instead. If make fails because of python, run configure with the --disable-docs command-line option.

Note also that curl | bash is a best practice...

cd ~/jq/docs
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=1.9.3
cd docs
bundle install
```

However, I am not sure how I am supposed to follow these steps while I am doing the jq install via pip3 in a virtual environment.

The [README.md](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/README.md) file in the jq documentation (of the current version) explains how to build the documentation, but again, I am not sure how to follow those steps while using pip3 in a virtual environment.

The jq documentation is not critical for me. I just want to properly install jq.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: "requirements.txt has this line among others: jq==1.0.2" so it's trying to install an ancient version of jq? Unless your OS somehow doesn't support it, you should use the latest or at least somewhat current version.

Comment: @JeffMercado Unfortunately I have to use this version.

Comment: @JeffMercado By the way, it looks like pip3 does try to install v1.6 anyway. See the top line of the error message in the question: "Downloaded https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-1.6.tar.gz"

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, Re "*so it's trying to install an ancient version of jq?*", No, it's installing 1.6 ("*Downloaded https://.../jq-1.6.tar.gz*")

Comment: @ikegami: well it was clear to me from the output that it was actually installing 1.6. But I don't know what `jq==1.0.2` means in this context, I can only assume the intent was to install that version.

Comment: The intent has no bearing on the problem at hand, though

Comment: @ikegami: frankly intent means everything in this question. `jq==1.0.2` means that pip should install that version [reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#requirements-file-format). The fact that it wasn't installing that version should have been an indicator that something else was not right. Since it turns out that updating pip fixed the issue, perhaps what happened was the _requested_ version of jq was installed and its dependencies (which is far less than what 1.6 requires).

Comment: It's like you didn't read the question. Nothing about the question pertains to 1.0.2: The workaround the OP is asking about are newer, and installing ruby was needed for 1.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not expect this, but this issue has been resolved after I updated `pip3` with this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then I used the same command to install the requirements, and this time, `jq` was installed successfully:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: But what version of jq ended up being installed?

Comment: I guess the version was the pip package version, not jq. https://pypi.org/project/jq/1.0.2/

Comment: Yes, @JeffMercado, v1.0.2 was installed.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to use this configure parameter when I am installing jq via pip3.

```sh
wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-1.6.tar.gz
tar xvzf jq-1.6.tar.gz
cd jq-1.6
./configure --disable-docs
make -j8
make check
```

Comment: (The other answer is obviously better, but figured it would be nice to have an answer to the question asked.)

Comment: Thanks for your input @ikegami. Would the code you shared do the compilation in the pyenv virtual environment? I am just asking to be sure.

Comment: `pyenv` appears to be a PATH manipulation tool. Presumably, the installer uses the first `python` or `python3` in the PATH, so yeah